# Why is this not an ambiguous call? (varargs parameters)

Tags: java

```
public class SomeClass{
          public SomeClass(String...test){}

          public SomeClass(String a, String b){}

          public void someMethod(String...test){}

          public void someMethod(String a, String b){}
}
```

How does the compiler know which constructor/method I meant if I write something like:

```
SomeClass c = new SomeClass("p1","p2"):
```

or

```
c.someMethod("p1","p2");
```

Answer (score 5):

There are 3 stages of method overload resolution. Only the 3rd and final stage considers methods with varargs as potential candidates (and that stage only takes place if the previous stages didn't find any matching candidate). Therefore, in your example, the compiler only considers the methods without varargs in the first step, and therefore has no ambiguity.

The reason for this behavior is that varargs methods were introduced in Java 5, and could have caused existing code to break if they were considered by the compiler in the first stage of method overload resolution.